# Ethereum geth linux installation directory, files details and enode strange IP address

Tags: go-ethereum

I follow ethe main website and install go ether through ppa repository
now i can only find a bin file in usr folder for ubuntu!

So is it the only file there for that?

AND

When i run these two instruction

```
geth --datadir ~/.ethereum_private init ~/dev/genesis.json

geth --fast --cache 512 --ipcpath ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc --networkid 12345 --datadir ~/.ethereum_private  console
```

And run command admin.nodeInfo.enode i got a address with IP after @! It is ok but the problem is that i got an IP address for my personal private node that is not my real external IP when I check my IP by other services out there! So what is this IP that is assigned to me? ( put ip here as reference to see if that maybe is some public cloud Ethereum address!!! 100.104.55.117:30303 )

Answer (score 1):

to share that enode with another client you just modify that strange ip with  your real external ip. 
It puts there that strange ip because the script for detecting your REAL external ip is not working as it should. Actually I noticed that it works as it should only on some VPS providers....